# Thank you Auden Young

Tags: discussion, moderation, diamond-moderators

I noticed that [Auden Young](https://stackexchange.com/users/8655359/auden-young) is no longer a diamond moderator on this site, and I just wanted to start a thank you thread here. Thank you Auden, I have appreciated some of your diamond moderation actions over the years, and also your contributions on Meta (for example, I recall appreciating [this one](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/513/2293)).